# First fight with Nemesis problem

Tags: resident-evil-3-nemesis

I played Resident Evil Nemesis a long time ago but was stuck on the first fight with Nemesis. My health was low then, and I couldn't find a way to defeat him. I tried to find some cheats that will skip that fight but couldn't, so I had to stop playing the game. I want to play this good game, so can anybody tell me the way to defeat him with very low health or some cheats to skip the fight? thanks in advance friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you stick to his right and run past him, turn around and blast him when he gets close. I think that pressing <kbd>o</kbd> at the right time will make you dodge by rolling away. You can avoid the fight completely by running into the station.

Answer (score 2):

You can try run by his right side, he will try to hit you with his left side. Once you passed him not too far or he will chase you, turn around and shoot him. Nemesis will fall but will get up again, so keep doing this until he falls and starts bleeding (purple blood).

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of videos called the "Handgun/Knives Challenge" that detail how to defeat nemesis using only the handgun and knife. [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTWy2FBXp4o) covers how to defeat him in the first battle outside the RPD. In general, there are several tips the author of the video outlines:

- Nemesis is left-handed. That means he'll punch and try to grab you with his left hand. You brush past his right shoulder to avoid getting grabbed. According to [File 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck2GxzuctzU), Nemesis needs to be on your left side to grab you.
- When he goes to grab you, you can time your shots to dodge his grabs.
- When he runs at you, it's possible to dodge, although difficult. It's best to run around and try to avoid his punch, and do a back-stutter (where you stop running and go backwards for a second, like you do when you dodge a zombie.)
- Don't back yourself into a corner. If you do this, you'll be unable to dodge, or you'll dodge into terrain. Even if you do dodge, Nemesis will have you pinned and grab you.

Nemesis can glitch on the terrain, allowing you to take pipe shots at him. It's most obvious in the second battle where you're in Martin Branagh's office. He'll keep walking into the shelf while you shoot at him. It can happen in other places although it is more difficult to reproduce.

The important thing is to keep your distance and minimize the amount of time you spend standing still. You might be frustrated at not being able to get in enough shots before nemesis grabs you. **Never** let Jill automatically reload, always reload from the inventory. Keep your finger on the trigger if you plan on shooting, and release it immediately if you plan on running. The draw animation wastes precious time which allows Nemesis to catch up to you.